# How to install MIMEDefang on Debian?

Tags: debian, postfix

I'm trying to install MIMEDefang on my Debian Stretch but it doesn't work out the of box and I can't find any guides that work.

After `apt install mimedefang` I added the following to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
milter_default_action = accept
```

Reloaded postfix, and `service mimedefang status` says it is *active* and *running*.

Even tried copying `/etc/mimedefang-filter` to `/etc/mail/mimedefang-filter` and made it executable...

But still I just get this in `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
postfix/smtpd[29832]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock: No such file or directory
```

The file `/var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock` exists though.

`sendmail` is already installed from before.

How do I install and activate this thing?

Comment: Please expand your question to explain how mimedefang is running, what you did to make it running. Any error logs?

Comment: I feel I have done that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the kind help of Benoît Panizzon on the MIMEDefang mailing list I found out that I need to use `inet` instead of `unix` as the listening socket, so that it's listening on the TCP port on the specified local or remote host. So the setup procedure for MIMEDefang on Debian/Ubuntu is:

1. Install MIMEDefang: `apt install mimedefang`
2. In `/etc/default/mimedefang` set (use other port if you want): `SOCKET=inet:33333`
3. Add to `/etc/postfic/main.cf`:

   `smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:33333
   milter_default_action = accept`
4. Copy `/etc/mimedefang-filter` to `/etc/mail/mimedefang-filter`, and modify it according to your needs (don't need to make it executable).
5. Reload Postfix and MIMEDefang services: `sudo systemctl reload postfix mimedefang`

MIMEDefang must be reloaded every time you change `mimedefang-filter`.

---

By the way, this presentation gives a good understanding of MIMEDefang: https://www.mimedefang.org/static/mimedefang-lisa04.pdf

The actual Perl script being run is located in `/usr/bin/mimedefang.pl` which then includes `mimedefang-filter`.

---

I also wanted to be able to write my filtering logic in **PHP** instead of Perl, so I came up with the following solution. Add this to the end of eg. the `filter_begin` function in `mimedefang-filter`:

```perl
%passToPhp = ("Sender", $Sender, "Recipients", \@Recipients, "Subject", $Subject, "RelayAddr", $RelayAddr, "RelayHostname", $RelayHostname, "Helo", $Helo, "QueueID", $QueueID, "MessageID", $MessageID);

my $cmd = "/path/to/your/email-filter.php";
$cmd .= " " . encode_base64(encode_json(\%passToPhp), '');
my $phpOutput = `$cmd`;

md_syslog('info', "PHP filter output: $phpOutput");  #causes entry in /var/log/mail.log
if ($phpOutput eq "bounce") {
    action_bounce("We dont want this particular message.");
} elsif ($phpOutput eq "discard") {
    action_discard();
}
```

Then use the following code in `email-filter.php` to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// runs as user "defang". This file must have execute permissions.

// Get variables from mimedefang that we passed along, headers, raw message, and extra information from mimedefang
$arguments = ($argv[1] ? base64_decode($argv[1]) : null);
if ($arguments) $arguments = json_decode($arguments, true);
$headers = file_get_contents('HEADERS');
$raw_message = file_get_contents('INPUTMSG');
$commands = file_get_contents('COMMANDS');

// Get all the MIME parts into an array
$mimeparts = [];
chdir('./Work');
foreach (glob('*') as $mimepart_file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) continue;
    $mimeparts[$mimepart_file] = file_get_contents($mimepart_file);
}

// Do all your logic here...

if ($someLogic == 'spam') {
    echo 'discard';
    // echo 'bounce';  //use this line if you want to have a bounce message sent back to sender (but you probably don't want that for spam)
}
```

Monitor `/var/log/mail.log` for ensuring everything works as it should.